# Populate a select from another in Wordpress and CF7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using Contact form 7 pugin in Wordpress. I need to populate a Select field with "crops" that are in a MySQL DB, and depending of the chosen one, a second Select has to be populated with this crop's "variety.

I know that using CF7 conditional fields it is possible, but there are 53 crops and more than 400 variety. So, it would be a lot of fields in DB and in the contact form.

I think it should be done using ajax, but I have no idea about this, and I can not find any example to learn using ajax + CF7 + Wordpress.
What I would like to do is make a query to MySQL (`Select variedad from cultivos where cultivo = 'id_cultivo'`) and populate the select with the result.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: This should not need AJAX, you can supply the necessary data in your server-side code using the appropriate hook. See https://www.leewillis.co.uk/dynamic-select-list-contact-form-7/ for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have things like that, but what I need to do is populate a Select field depending of the value of another select field. For example, if you choose the value "Europe" from first select, the second one must show "Spain", "France", "Germany".... If you choose "Asia", the second has to show "China, Japan, India"..... and everything being loaded from the MySQL table, because there are many options to chose in the first Select.

Comment: Well then this isn’t really that connected to cf7 begin with ... Your research should start with how to use AJAX in WordPress, and how to populate a select field with options based on some data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to populate a Select field with "crops" that are in a MySQL DB

Use a dynamic dropdown field from the [Smart Grid plugin extension for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/).

It allows you to populate your dropdown using either a set of existing post or a taxonomy, else iit also has the ability to populate using a hook, so you can build a custom sql if your 'crops' are in a custom table.

> and depending of the chosen one, a second Select has to be populated with this crop's "variety.

so this is trickier.  The dynamic dropdown populated using a taxonomy allows you to build a jquery [select2](https://select2.org/) dropdown which makes it much easier to search through long lists of options, furthermore, if your taxonomy is hierarchical (2 level deep), it will use the parent level terms as option groups in the dowdown and actual options will be the child terms.  Hence you could organise your 'crops' and 'varieties' as a taxonomy of parent->child terms.  Crops that have no variety would simply have itself as a variety, and your dropdown would allow users to select a variety within a specific category.

This would make it simpler to setup on your form, without the requirement of hidden dropdowns.  It is also a lot more scalable & maintainable, as whenever you update your crop/variety terms, it is dynamically reflected in the form without having to change your form.

I hope all the above makes sense.  If you wish to explore this further, you can post on the plugin support forum.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer. I will try these clues you give me in order to do things in the future. I have solve the trouble by now...I will post how.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following lines in order to solve my trouble:

In js file:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $("#idsubfamilia").change(function(e) {


                 e.preventDefault();
         jQuery.post(MyAjax.url, {action : 'buscar_posts' ,cadena : $('#idsubfamilia').val() }, function(response) {
//                $('#variedad_container').hide().html(response).fadeIn();
$('#variedad_container').hide().html(response).fadeIn();
            });
    });

});
```

In functions.php (thanks to http://masquewordpress.com/como-utilizar-ajax-correctamente-en-wordpress/):

```
/* AJAX */

// Primero incluimos nuestro archivo javascript definido anteriormente
wp_enqueue_script( 'mi-script-ajax',get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/ajax-search.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

// ahora declaramos la variable MyAjax y le pasamos el valor url (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php) al script ajax-search.js
wp_localize_script( 'mi-script-ajax', 'MyAjax', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

//Para manejar admin-ajax tenemos que añadir estas dos acciones.
//IMPORTANTE!! Para que funcione reemplazar "buscar_posts" por vuestra action definida en ajax-search.js

add_action('wp_ajax_buscar_posts', 'buscar_posts_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_buscar_posts', 'buscar_posts_callback');

function buscar_posts_callback() {

        global $wpdb;
    $subfamilia=$_POST['cadena'];
    //$datos = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT id, subfamilia_' . $idioma . ' FROM wp_custom_subfamilias  ORDER BY subfamilia_' . $idioma);
    $datos = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT variedad FROM wp_custom_variedad where subfamilia_fk='".$subfamilia."' ORDER BY variedad");

     echo '<ul>';
echo '<select name="selectVariedad" id="idSelectVariedad">';
    foreach ($datos as $dato) {


       echo "<option value='".$dato->variedad."'>".$dato->variedad."</option>";


    }
echo '</select>';
     echo '</ul>';
    die(); // Siempre hay que terminar con die

}
```